# JSGrid is not getting updated with search values

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jsgrid

Im updating the grid values from the database. And passing values from CS page to JSgrid. Delete,Edit is perfectly working with db. But after search the grid is not getting updated.I can pass the search value to the CS page and get the corresponding search value from DB. But the values are not getting updated with JSgrid.

```
     var Status;        
    var lastPrevItem;
    var clients =<%=gridData%>

    $("#jsGrid").jsGrid({
        width: "100%",
        height: "450px",

        filtering: true, 
        //filterable:true,
        //inserting: true,
        autosearch: true,
        editing: true,
        sorting: true,
        paging: true,
        autoload: true,
        pageSize: 25,
        pageButtonCount: 5,
        deleteConfirm: "Do you really want to delete the Department?",

        controller:   //db,
            {  loadData: function (filter) {   
                  if (filter["ID"] != "" || filter["Name"] != "") {
                     return $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        async: true,
                        processdata: false,
                        paging: true,
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        url: "myurl/mycsmethod",
                        data: "{'ID':'" + filter["ID"] + "','Name':'" + filter["Name"]+ "'}",    

                        success: function (data) {

                        },
                        error: function (XHR, errStatus, errorThrown) {
                            var err = JSON.parse(XHR.responseText);
                            errorMessage = err.Message;
                            alert(errorMessage);
                        }
                    });
                  }
            },
            updateItem: function (clients) {
                var result = $.Deferred();
                alert(result);
                var ajaxDeferred = $.Deferred().reject();
                alert(ajaxDeferred);
                ajaxDeferred.done(function (updatedItem) {
                    result.resolve(updatedItem);
                }).fail(function () {
                    result.resolve(lastPrevItem);
                });
                return result.promise();
            },
            },

        onItemDeleting: function (args) {
          //its working fine
        },
        onItemEditing: function (args) {
            //its working fine
        },

        data: clients,

        fields: [
            { type: "control" },
            { name: "ID", visible: false, width: 0, validate: "required" },
            { name: "Name", visible: false, width: 0, validate: "required" },
        ]
    });
```

I want to update <%=gridData%> with jsgrid once the search button is triggered.

Comment: `lodaData` should always return a promise or just static array of items. In your working example, you implemented client-side filtering. If you want to implement server-side filtering (as in your question above), just always return `$.ajax` (not conditionally). The filtering will call `loadData`, which will send filtering parameters to the server, returned by `$.ajax` promise will be resolved with filtered data, and it should work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

```
loadData: function(filter) {
                    return $.grep(clients, function(client) {
                        return (!filter["DeptID"] || client["DeptID"].indexOf(filter["DeptID"]) > -1)
                            && (!filter["DeptName"] || client["DeptName"].indexOf(filter["DeptName"])>-1)
                            && (!filter["Status"] || client["Status"].indexOf(filter["Status"]) > -1)
                    });},

updateItem: function (updatingClient) {
                    var result = $.Deferred();
                    alert(result);
                    var ajaxDeferred = $.Deferred().reject();
                    alert(ajaxDeferred);
                    ajaxDeferred.done(function (updatedItem) {
                        result.resolve(updatedItem);
                    }).fail(function () {
                        result.resolve(lastPrevItem);
                    });
                    return result.promise();
                },
```

Its working now with the above code,friends.But If anything,i need to improve in my code, please let me know.